# Using a local Open API Standard file to to create an ARM template for a web service

Tags: json, azure, azure-api-management

I am working on an old web service where I generate the rest endpoints documentation that comply with OAS standards using a custom tool. Using this OAS json file I can deploy the API to Azure API Managements services through the portal and it all works fine. However, I need to automate this process and hence need to use ARM templates to deploy all web services to Azure APIM. I have been looking into the examples provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis but just can't seem to wrap my head around how to use a local OAS.json file or a file in github.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "apiManagementServiceName": "price-capture"
  },
  "resources": [    
    {      
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
      "name": "[variables('apiManagementServiceName')]",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "Service display Name",
        "apiRevision": "1",
        "description": "API description",
      //need help since it's not a swagger url 
      //wondering if there is a way to ref a local file like the option 
      //provided in the portal when we register api's manually.
        "serviceUrl": "----", 
        "path": "----",                            
        "protocols": [    
            "https"
        ],            
        "isCurrent": true,
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "apiVersionDescription": "apiVersionDescription"        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer ..all I had to do was write an azure function that fetches the oas.yaml file from a private github repository.

```
"variables":{
    "swagger_json":"[concat(parameters('url_of_azurefunctionwithaccesskey'),'&&githuburi='parameter('raw_url'),'&githubaccesstoken=',parameter('personalaccesstoken')]" 
},
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('apimName') ,'/' ,parameters('serviceName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "apiRevision": "[parameters('apiRevision')]",
                "path": "pricecapture",
                "contentValue": "[variables('swagger_json')]",
                "contentFormat": "openapi-link"
            }
        }]
```

The Azure function that I had to write was something like this:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var gitHubUri = req.Query["githuburi"];

    var gitHubAccessToken = req.Query["githubaccesstoken"];
    var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gitHubUri))
    {

        var errorcontent = new StringContent("please pass the raw file content URI (raw.githubusercontent.com) in the request URI string", Encoding.ASCII);
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            Content = errorcontent
        };
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gitHubAccessToken))
    {
        var errorcontent = new StringContent("please pass the GitHub personal access token in the request URI string", Encoding.ASCII);
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            Content = errorcontent
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var strAuthHeader = "token " + gitHubAccessToken;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.raw");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", strAuthHeader);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(gitHubUri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy and configure an entire API on API Management via ARM templates, but you cannot use a local file to provide the OpenApi/Swagger. 
In your case the OpenApi/Swagger needs to be publicly accessible so the resource manager can read from it, so if the Github URL is freely accessible it should work.
I typically store the OpenApi/Swagger to a storage account and use the SAS token to access it from the ARM template.

You can check out this blog for details on automating API deployment in APIM:
https://blog.eldert.net/api-management-ci-cd-using-arm-templates-linked-template/

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the API using an `Azure Resource Manager` template of type `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis`, and to use an Open API / swagger definition you need to specify the `contentValue` and and `contentFormat` parameters of the [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2018-06-01-preview/service/apis)

```
{
  "name": "awesome-api-management/petstore",
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
  "properties": {
    "path": "petstore"
    "contentValue": "petstore swagger file contents here", // or it's URL
    "contentFormat": "swagger-json", // or swagger-link-json if externally available
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to deploy the APIs configs via templates.

I've been trying to figure this out myself but I'm pretty sure you can't include the actual APIs you want in the service.

From what I can tell, you can't do that with the GIT repo either because that needs authentication that is manually created in the portal

I think the only thing you can automate with the ARM template is the actual API Management service and then you need to use the Azure API to add and configure the APIs on it.

However, I have yet to figure out how to do that myself.

I actually have a service ticket open to get help on that.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed slightly so this works:

The yaml file (calculatorApiFile) needs to be uploaded first to a blob storage, but this can be done as part of the deployment pipeline

```
 {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
            "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('service_name'), '/b12b1d5ab8204cg6b695e3e861fdd709')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Calculator",
                "apiRevision": "1",
                "description": "A simple Calculator ",                   
                "path": "calc",
                "value": "[concat(parameters('containerUri'), parameters('calculatorApiFile'), parameters('containerSasToken'))]",
                "format": "openapi-link",
                "protocols": [
                    "https"
                ],
                "isCurrent": true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load your YAML into a variable, that can be passed to the ARM template and be passed as the value:

deploy.bat:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set API_DEPLOYMENT=<deployment name>
set API_GROUP=<deployment group>
set API=<api file path.yml>
set OPENAPI=
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type %API%') do set "OPENAPI=!OPENAPI!%%x\n"
call az deployment group create -n %API_DEPLOYMENT% -g %API_GROUP% --mode Complete -f deploy.json -p openApi="!OPENAPI!"
ENDLOCAL
```

deploy.json (note the use of replace)

```
...
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('apiName')]",
            "properties": {
                "path": "[variables('service')]",
                "apiType": "http",
                "displayName": "[variables('apiDisplayName')]",
                "format": "openapi",
                "value": "[replace(parameters('openApi'), '\\n', '\n')]"
            },
            ...
        },
...
```